# Why can't map ctrl+. with <C-X><C-O>?

Tags: key-bindings

I map `.` with `<C-X><C-O>` in `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap . <C-X><C-O>
```

The map command `inoremap . <C-X><C-O>` take effect ,i want to map `ctrl + .`  with `<C-X><C-O>`,
why `inoremap <C-.> <C-X><C-O>` can't work?

Comment: At least on my Vim, if I enter `<C-v>` followed by `<C-.>` in Insert mode, Vim just inserts a `.`, which tells me that Vim simply sees `<C-.>` as `.`

Comment: What version of Vim you use? What terminal? What OS? What's the output of `set t_TE? t_TI?` ?